# image_dataset_from_directory VS flow_from_directory

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, data-science-model

What is the main diffrence between flow_from_directory **VS** image_dataset_from_directory in keras?

which one should I use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> **tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory**
>
> *Generates a tf.data.Dataset from image files in a directory*.

> **ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory**
>
> *Takes the path to a directory & generates batches of augmented data*.

While their return type also differs but the key difference is that *flow_from_directory* is a method of ImageDataGenerator while *image_dataset_from_directory* is a preprocessing function to read image form directory.

*image_dataset_from_directory* will not facilitate you with augmented image generation capability on-the-fly.

> which one should I use?

It's quite common to generate augmented images when working with CNN, so better to use *flow_from_directory*.
If you do not need augmented image, you may control the same by the parameters of *ImageDataGenerator*

[*Reference - Keras docs*](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/#imagedatagenerator-class)

Answer (score 0):

Some response elements can be found in this interesting [post](https://towardsdatascience.com/time-to-choose-tensorflow-data-over-imagedatagenerator-215e594f2435)

As mentioned above:

> tf.keras.preprocessing**.image_dataset_from_directory**  Generates a
> **tf.data.Dataset** from image files in a directory.

The **.image_dataset_from_directory** function/method enables the use of the new tf 2.8.x (and later version) data structure **tf.data.Dataset**.
Rather than loading your data into lists, which is not a recommended practice, the **.image_dataset_from_directory** allows to load your data in the **tf.data.Dataset** format.
Hence, it enables also the use, and this is the best, of the [Keras preprocessing layers](https://keras.io/guides/preprocessing_layers/), including data augmentation.
Contrary to what is being said that:

> image_dataset_from_directory will not facilitate you with augmented
> image generation capability on-the-fly.

the **.image_dataset_from_director** allows to put data in a format that can be directly pluged into the **keras pre-processing layers**, and data augmentation is run on the fly (real time) with other downstream layers.

This is the main advantage beside allowing the use of the advantageous **tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices** method.

To sum up, **.image_dataset_from_director** is an upgraded version of **.flow_from_directory** for handling datasets and passing them to deep learning models.