# Low accuracy VGG16 model when using ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory but high accuracy using image_dataset_from_directory as inputs

Tags: vgg16

I am currently trying to understand why is it that a certain model gives very different accuracy results when using two different ways to input the same training dataset to train it.

I have the following model:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

conv_base = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16(
    weights="imagenet", 
    include_top=False
    )

conv_base.trainable = True
for layer in conv_base.layers[:-4]:
    layer.trainable = False

data_augmentation_CVGG = keras.Sequential(
    [layers.RandomFlip("horizontal"),
     layers.RandomRotation(0.2),
     layers.RandomZoom(0.2)])

inputs_CVGG = keras.Input(shape=(150, 150, 3))
x = data_augmentation_CVGG(inputs_CVGG)
x = keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input(x)
x = conv_base(x)

x = layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(x)

x = layers.Flatten()(x)
x = layers.Dense(512)(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.4)(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)
model_CNN_VGG = keras.Model(inputs_CVGG, outputs)

model_CNN_VGG.summary()

model_CNN_VGG.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=1e-5), 
              metrics=["accuracy"])
```

If I use the generators from the following as input:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen_CVGG = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_datagen_CVGG = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator_CVGG = train_datagen_CVGG.flow_from_directory(
                                                    base_dir+"/"+"train", 
                                                    batch_size=20, 
                                                    class_mode='binary', 
                                                    target_size=(150, 150))
validation_generator_CVGG = test_datagen_CVGG.flow_from_directory(
                                                        base_dir+"/"+"validation", 
                                                        batch_size=20, 
                                                        class_mode='binary', 
                                                        target_size=(150, 150))
```

and train the model with:

```
history = model_CNN_VGG.fit(
    train_generator_CVGG,
    epochs=20, 
    verbose=2, 
    validation_data=validation_generator_CVGG)
```

I get very low accuracy (50~60%). But the problem is that it doesn't improve a whole lot with more epochs.

Now, consider the following:

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import image_dataset_from_directory

train_dataset = image_dataset_from_directory(
    base_dir+"/"+"train",
    image_size=(150, 150),
    batch_size=20)
validation_dataset = image_dataset_from_directory(
    base_dir+"/"+"validation",
    image_size=(150, 150),
    batch_size=20)

history = model_CNN_VGG.fit(
    train_dataset,
    epochs=20,
    verbose=2,
    validation_data=validation_dataset)
```

This way, the **exact** same model immediately gives accuracy over 85% and gets over 95% after a few epochs.

I have searched around but every other similar question focuses on improving the accuracy of the first method (.flow_from_directory()) by tweaking parameters. I have tried different learning rates, different optmizers, etc etc but the accuracy doesn't get better. Besides, I am not trying to get the accuracy to go higher, I am trying to understand why is it so much better using image_dataset_from_directory than ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory

I already read [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/78405/image-dataset-from-directory-vs-flow-from-directory) but that doesn't explain the differences in the outcome of training the same model both ways.

What am I missing?
Thanks.